# Are unions of independent events independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X$ be a finite set of (mutually) independent events. Let $X_1 = \{A_{11}, ..., A_{1i_1}\}, X_2 = \{A_{21}, ..., A_{2i_2}\}, ..., X_n = \{A_{n1}, ..., A_{ni_n}\}$ be pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$.

Is it true that $\displaystyle P\left((\bigcup X_1) \cap (\bigcup X_2) \cap ... \cap \bigcup (X_n)\right) = P(\bigcup X_1) P(\bigcup X_2) ... P(\bigcup X_n)$?

---

Intuitively, it seems like it should be true, since the subsets are disjoint. It also appears to be true for a binomial coin toss example, but I may be wrong. (Also, I am mostly interested only in non-degenerate cases; so, if necessary, you could assume things like $X_i$ are all non-empty, or that all events in question have non-zero probability, etc.)

Comment: Hint: Events are independent iff their complements are independent. What happens if $\bigcup X_i$ is replaced by $\bigcap X_i$ in your equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $A_{ij}$ are all mutually independent, then yes, and more generally: the $\sigma$-algebras generated by disjoint collections of mutually independent events are independent. So you could use $\bigcap$ instead of $\bigcup$, or any other expressions involving union, intersection and complement.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1 \cap \{ \emptyset \}, \dots, X_n \cap \{ \emptyset \}$ are $\pi$-systems (stable under intersection) then independence of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ implies independence of $\sigma(X_1), \dots, \sigma(X_n)$. This is part of Theorem 2.13 (iii) in *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*, by Klenke.

Independence of $\sigma(X_1), \dots, \sigma(X_n)$, of course, would imply your desired equation and much more besides.